# CAN I use conditional logic in my mysql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm constantly fighting SPAM so I want to limit users from contacting no more then 40 new unique members per day.

My current DB schema for tracking messages looks like this

```
id   sender receiver content  date                   belong_to
100  5      7        send1    2013-02-08 09:31:36    5  
101  5      7        send1    2013-02-08 09:31:36    7
102  7      5        recevd   2013-02-08 09:32:18    7
103  7      5        recevd   2013-02-08 09:32:18    5
```

My current Query looks like this to return the number of distinct recipients in the past 24 hours:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(receiver)) 
FROM `messages` 
WHERE sender = 5 
AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

The output based on this example is 1 but since the user responded I would want this excluded from the count.

Based on my example data I would want to exclude these two entried from my count because the receiver has responded to the sender.  How would I account for unique recipients in the past 24 hours but exclude any number of recipients who have responded to this sender since the beginning of time?

Comment: the what would be the output based on the example above?

Comment: @JW I just added the actual result and expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(receiver)) 
FROM `messages` m, 
WHERE sender = X  
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM `messages` m2 where receiver = X and sender = m.reciever )
AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Doesn't look like your table has any way of disambiguating individual messages/ which message is being replied to, which could be an issue.